# UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `util`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native, npm-install

I use xml2json in my react native project, while running the app, I get error message

```
UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `events`
This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --reset-cache`.
```

also occurred in other third-part modules, they are all nodejs core modules that cannot be resolved.
Need your help, thx : )

Comment: Not positive you can do this, Node Core libraries ultimately depend on V8 and a C implementation which is absent on mobile devices so you can't just bundle them in like that to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: The same issue (( Any news?

Answer (score -3):

The message shows that the specified module doesn't exist in the dependency. The way I fix it is to just re-install the module package which the error message specifies.

In your case
`npm install --save util`

Hope this helps!